# css3 transition - custom style

Tags: css, css-transitions

Transition should work only width and height only

```
logo-small {
    top:0 ;
    width:198px;
    height:198px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0s;

} 
logo-small:hover {
    top:100px ;
    width:298px;
    height:298px;
}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: your code works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/exenor/1/edit

Comment: @ Fabrizio Calderan  ????? read now my question

Comment: is your question "I want a transition only for width and height and not also for position?"

Comment: The question is very confusing, please write clearly..

Comment: Yes , position should not animate

Comment: @Riccardo Pasianotto , Did you understand now ? Read it again Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified the transition should affect all properties. try

```
#logo-small:hover {
    transition-property: width, height;
    top:100px ;
    width:298px;
    height:298px;
}
```

or

```
#logo-small {
    top:0 ;
    width:198px;
    height:198px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out 0s, width 2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s ease-in-out 0s, width 2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: height 2s ease-in-out 0s, width 2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

edit: added back old answer, fixed

Comment: I think your's first answer is best method

Comment: Oh, maybe, but I posted it before testing it, and it didn't work. This was the quickest way to fix the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are getting this bug on Moz Firefox only:
Here is the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821976

create different css class for adding effect and apply this class on hover by javascript

```
.newClass {
    top:100px ;
    width:298px;
    height:298px;
}

$('.logo-small').on('hover', function(){
    $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

And don't forget to remove on mouse out.